# How to control visibility of text in all listboxitems on selection of one item in dynamic Listbox Menu?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I generate ListBox menu from XML. I use datatemplate to style the behavior of listboxitems on selection and other states. I need to hide all textblocks in all listboxitems on selection of the item which gets a value ‘retract’ from XML. Now, I am able to hide texblock only in listboxitem which has this value but cannot hide textblocks in other listboxitems. I am wondering if someone can help. Thank you in advance.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="DataItem">
            <Image x:Name="IconImage" Source="{Binding XPath=@icon}" Height="16" Margin="16,0,0,0" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ListboxIemtextBlock" Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
            <Image x:Name="ArrowImage" Height="10" Source="Resources/Images/arrow_collapsed_grey.png" Visibility="{Binding XPath=@state}"/>
        </Grid>
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter TargetName="IconImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding XPath=@iconSelected}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="IconImage" Property="Height" Value="16"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ArrowImage" Property="Source" Value="Resources/Images/arrow_collapsed_white.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#FF6dacbe"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>         
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>           
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True" />           
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True" />         
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>         
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>      
            </MultiDataTrigger> 
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@retract}" Value="True" >             
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>      
            </DataTrigger> 
         </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It looks like I cannot control the visibility of all texblocks from a datatemplate. I think it should be done in the ListBox style. I was thinking to switch datatemplates with a second datatemplate that does not have texblock at all. I wanted to use multitrigger for conditions with values isSelected and XML-Binding to Binding="{XPath=@retract}. However, I cannot assign XPath binding for multitrigger in Listbox style. Perphaps, you might help to bind it correctly or have a better idea on how to hide texblocks.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemDataTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>      
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{XPath=@retract}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedListBoxItemDataTemplate}"/> 
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>  
    </Style>
```

I populated XML with XMLDataProvider. I reference to xml this way:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="PagesData" XPath="/Pages" Source="Data/DataSource.xml" />
```

XML:

```
<Pages xmlns="">
<page name="Item 1" icon="Resources/Iocn1.png" retract="False" />
<page name="Item 2" icon="Resources/Iocn2.png" retract="False" />
<page name="Item 3" icon="Resources/Iocn3.png" retract="True" /></Pages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the SelectedItem.retract for the Parent ListBox. This is a working example using Path instead of XPath (since I don't have your XML source) but you should be able to get it to work the same way

Add this trigger in the DataTemplate

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=SelectedItem.retract}" Value="True" >
    <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my thread. I added XML sample. I need to be able to hide all texblocks in all three listboxItems on selection of the lisboxitem when its 'retract' attribute with value equals 'true'. In other instances, nothing should be changed. This datatrigger will hide only one listboxitem which is selected. I am wondering if you have an idea on how to hide texblocks in other listboxitems. Thank you.

Comment: @vladc77, it will hide all TextBlocks for ListBoxItems since every ListBoxItem is triggering on the selected item in the ListBox

Comment: I just tested it and it hides only texblock in listboxitem that is selected. I edited my previous comment. I added this datatrigger in 'ListBoxItemDataTemplate' datatemplate.

Comment: @vladc77: I uploaded my sample project here: http://www.mediafire.com/?pdxk8ftbcqgrix4 If you select the ListBoxItem "name3" then all TextBlocks will be hidden. I'll look at your XML example

Comment: @vladc77: I forgot to add the images as resources.. I'll fix that

Comment: I still cannot access XML from the sample above. At the moment, I was thinking I did but now it seems not. I don't need to control visibility of the images. They shoul be intact. I only need to hide or remove textblock. Thank you again.

Comment: @vladc77: I uploaded my sample project here: http://www.mediafire.com/?d961x6gt3noso3d If you select the ListBoxItem "name3" then all TextBlocks will be hidden

Comment: @vladc77: Look at my new sample, I think that's what you're after. It doesn't change the visibility of the Images, just the TextBlocks. Or did I missunderstand the question?

Comment: I just got it. Great sample!!! It works. I only have a minor issue. I cannot access 'retract' attribute the same way as you do because I generate it with XMLDataprovider. What would be the correct way to access it? Thank you again.

Comment: @vladc77: Not sure, I'll need to look at that. Can you add the full code for the XMLDataProvider to your question? That'd be helpful :)

Comment: Yes, I already added it in the question area. It is in the end.

Comment: @vladc77: Got my folks coming over now so I'll have to look at it later tonight if you haven't solved it already by then :) Merry xmas

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep looking. I will let you know if I will find the way to access it. Merry xmas! Sorry for bothering.

Comment: I fixed it. DataTrigger binding should be done this way: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=SelectedItem.Attributes[retract].Value}" Value="True">. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can I have a delay for a datatrigger to be in effect? For example hide the texblock on 0.5 sec.